# VBA code to take chart maximum and place it in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I have a chart sheet, from this I want to be able to take the maximum value of the primary axis and  place the value in a cell in a different sheet. I have no idea how to tackle this

Comment: `MAX` on it's series data source?

Comment: from the image i've added it would take the 400 and place that into a cell

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub t()

Dim c As Chart
Set c = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 16").Chart

Dim a As Axis
Set a = c.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue)

Debug.Print a.MaximumScale

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, How do I implement this so that it works for my chart sheet?